# Suppressing SSL errors

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I want to be able to read the headers sent back from a webpage in SSL mode. My Qt app however can't reach the webpage because it's in SSL mode I am gathering? Normal webview browsing in SSL is possible in my app using this connect:

```
connect(view->page()->networkAccessManager(), SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )),
                        this, SLOT(onSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));
```

This suppresses the SSL errors in the webview but I have a separate function which get's the headers using this method:

```
//Send a request to validate URL
QNetworkAccessManager *manager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
QNetworkRequest request;
request.setUrl(QUrl(text));
request.setRawHeader("User-Agent", "MyApp1.0");
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                  QNetworkReply *reply = manager->get(request);
QEventLoop loop;
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
loop.exec();

qDebug() << "QLoop: " << reply->rawHeader("My-Application");
  if(reply->rawHeader("My-Application") == "1"){
      appUrl = text;
  }
```

I need this method because I set a config file with our webapps URL in it before the the app will connect to it using `webview->load(QURL(appUrl ))`. Just not sure how to supress/handle SSL errors using QNetworkAccessManager?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to connect your QNAM objects signal `sslErrors(QNetworkReply *, QList<QSslError>)` to a slot where you set `QNetworkReply::ignoreSslErrors()` and that'll allow QNAM to continue running.  [Qt Docs on it](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#sslErrors).

Comment: Thanks very much, I tried `reply->ignoreSslErrors();` in the middle somewhere lol and it didn't work so I'll give your method a go :)

Comment: No bother, first time I tried it I completely ignored that the signal was being emitted and put `reply->ignoreSslErrors()` where I created QNAM. Simple mistake!

Comment: Only thing I am finding is `SIGNAL(sslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )), SLOT(onSslErrors(QNetworkReply*, const QList<QSslError> & )));` sometimes get's fired sometimes doesn't? Maybe I am implimenting it wrong? This is my first Qt application lol - @Nicholas Smith