# How to disable OpenSSL in QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: c++, qt, openssl

I am working with Qt 5.2. I am using `QNetworkAccessManager` to make some posts to a web (without encryption). Now I have to verify a signature of message (That message has nothing to do with the post and `QNetworkAccessManager`, they are completly separated).

Both parts of code work fine separately, but when they come together the application crashes. If I add the OpenSSL to the application and I call a `QNetworkAccessManager::post` then it fails. The program pointer is in `OPENSSL_sk_pop_free` and it crashes after a `QNetworkAccessManager::post` call.

The code:

```
//#define OPENSSL

#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <openssl/bio.h>

#if defined(OPENSSL)
#define USE_SHA1
bool validateLicense()
{
    BIO* bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

    BIO_free(bio);

    return true;
}
#endif


int main() {
    QNetworkAccessManager* manager = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("http:\\192.168.0.1"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/json"));

    QString com("{\"hello world\"}");

    QByteArray data(com.toLocal8Bit());

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "data to POST" << com;

    manager->post(request, data);

#if defined(OPENSSL)
    validateLicense();
#endif
}
```

The .pro file:

```
QT += core network
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = console
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

#
# libcrypto
#
LIBS += $$[OPENSSL_INSTALL_ROOT]/libcrypto.a
```

If I uncomment the `#define OPENSSL` the application crashes in line `manager->post(request, data);`.

How can I disable the OpenSSL in `QNetworkAccessManager` to avoid the application crash?

Comment: Can you post Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or can you show us the code and context in which this happens ?

Comment: I believe QT depends on OpenSSL for its Crypto and SSL gear. If you disable OpenSSL, then you probably won't be able to verify the signature.

Comment: @jww I verify the signature by calling the OpenSLL library directly, without any Qt classes.

Comment: Well, I can't answer the Qt part since I'm not a Qt user. Sorry about that. Regarding the bad interaction between Qt's version of OpenSSL and your version of OpenSSL, I *think* the way to proceed is a wrapper shared object like Android needs to avoid problems with Zygote's down level version of OpenSSL. For that discussion, see [OpenSSL  and Android | Wrapper Shared Objects](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android#Wrapper_Shared_Objects) on the OpenSSL wiki

Comment: @JMA The question is not very clear but I suspect something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277694/suppressing-ssl-errors